# PriorityQueue and compareTo method

Tags: java, dijkstra

A small question but I can't find a good explanation on how to achieve what I am trying. I am trying to implement a [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). And I need to use a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

I want to compare the different vertices of a graph depending on their distance.
But I don't really know how to write such a compare method because I have never used a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Yes but I did not get how to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for CompareTo function:

```
public class Example implements Comparable<Example> {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Example o) {
        return this.test.compareTo(o.test);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the priority queue is that it keeps the smallest element at the top.
You can retrieve this top element with the `peek()` function or retrieve it and remove it from the queue with the `pop()` function.

So for the Dijkstra algorithm you should put all vertices in the queue and then at each step pop the one that has the smallest distance and then update the distances to its neighbors in the queue.

Comment: the problem is I get an error when I put the vertices into the queue. I guess it is because they have no base on which they can be compared.